Static MySQL XDevApi library failed to build in VSCode CMake Project
So I'm currently trying to make xdevapi work with cpp-httplib. This is my current CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(http-server VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include_directories(
    dependencies/include 
    api 
    external/dotenv
)

set(MYSQL_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 9.0")
include_directories(PUBLIC ${MYSQL_DIR}/include)

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    api/server/restful.cpp
    api/server/handlers.cpp
    api/server/middleware.cpp
    api/server/routing.cpp
    api/database/mysqldb.cpp
)

add_executable(main ${SOURCES})

find_library(mysqlcppconnx_static_LIB
    mysqlcppconnx-static
    HINTS ${MYSQL_DIR}/lib64/vs14
)

message(STATUS "MySQL Connector C++ library found: ${mysqlcppconnx_static_LIB} at ${MYSQL_DIR}/lib64/vs14")

target_link_libraries(main 
    PUBLIC ${mysqlcppconnx_static_LIB}
)

I'm currently using vscode and I used a static library for the MySQL Connector C++, and cmake was okay with that; intellisense worked as well.
However when I built the project, this popped up:
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (__imp_?print@Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@MBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::print(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?print@Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::Value(void)" (__imp_??0Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::Value(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value &&)" (??0Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@$$QAV0123@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::Value(__int64)" (__imp_??0Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@_J@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::Value(__int64)" (??0Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@_J@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: enum mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::Type __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::get_type(void)const " (__imp_?get_type@Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QBE?AW4Type@12345@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::print(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?print@Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::~Value(void)" (__imp_??1Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@$$QAV0123@@Z$0
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value & __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::operator=(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value &&)" (__imp_??4Value@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAEAAV01234@$$QAV01234@@Z) referenced in function "public: class mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value & __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::operator=(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value &&)" (??4Value@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAEAAV0123@$$QAV0123@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Settings_impl::set_from_uri(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?set_from_uri@Settings_impl@common@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::ClientSettings::ClientSettings(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const &)" (??0ClientSettings@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@QAE@ABVstring@123@@Z)

This is only part of the error message, but almost every other line had similar messages.
I assume this might be because I'm lacking the dlls, but I'm using the static lib file so it shouldn't need it? I am honestly confused...
UPDATE
I referred to the MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 Developer Guide and most of the dll errors are gone. I only needed to add this line to my CMakeLists.txt:
add_definitions(-DSTATIC_CONCPP)

However, these errors still remain:
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::hasField(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?hasField@DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UBE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value const & __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::operator[](class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (??ADbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UBEABVValue@123@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::print(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?print@DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::Iterator __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::begin(void)" (?begin@DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UAE?AVIterator@1234@XZ)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::Iterator __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::end(void)" (?end@DbDoc@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@UAE?AVIterator@1234@XZ)
[build] mysqldb.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: class mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail & __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::operator=(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail &&)" (??4Result_detail@internal@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@IAEAAV01234@$$QAV01234@@Z) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::Result_detail(class mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail &&)" (??0Result_detail@internal@r0@abi2@mysqlx@@IAE@$$QAV01234@@Z)


While your code attempts to link to a static library, the errors say your missing linking to an import library for a dll and not a static library. My guess is there is some way to configure mysql connector and its headers probably via some preprocessor macro to tell it you are using the static library instead of the default and expected dll that most users will use.

That helped solved most of the errors thank you.
